# How to compile a set of C files with a set of object files in C

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linker, makefile, object-files

So my question is that i have a set of C files (Lot of them), 
I have another set of c files which are already compiled and they are translated to type .o(object) and .d (dependency)

My Questions:

- Now in my project I have to add the second set of object files and compile Successfully the complete stand and create a binary out of it.
- What are the different ways of achieving this (pros and cons)

**Required info:**
 - C compilation
 - GNU tool chain
 - Hightec compiler

Please let me know if any more information is needed

Comment: Read more about [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). If on Linux, read also [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

Comment: You first bullet point doesn't make any sense. What second set of object files? Add them to what? What does "compile Successfully the complete stand" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you no longer need to touch the source code of the second set (the set of object files) and it contains no dependency on the first one (the set of .c files), I would simply cram all its .o files into a separate library and then link to it at the end.

Comment: Assumption 1. There would not be any change, Assumption 2: there can be dependencies for some files in list 1 on object files in list 2

Comment: As long as no object files in list 2 depend on c files in list 1, then, IMHO, treating list 2 as a separate library is the natural way to go.

Comment: the object files in list 2 may not depend on .c files from list 1 ... The c files might be dependent on the object files in list 2

Comment: Yes, I think we're on the same page.